# Failed installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-8

I was trying to install ubuntu 16.04.3 in dual boot mode on my PC which is pre-installed with Windows 8.1 by following this [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) Everything was on its way, but suddenly ubuntu installer crashed at the point where we select nearest location/city.
[image: Select location/city]

Later I reinstalled ubuntu again, but it didn't helped me. When I start PC it starts in windows and if I reboot manually from USB from UEFI settings it again shows the options to **Install Ubuntu** and **Try Ubuntu without installing**. That means ubuntu is not installed properly I guess.

The **Grub** menu didn't launched at all.

I don't understand now what to do next. Windows partition looks like
[image: windows partition]

I have disabled secure boot mode
[image: secure boot mode]
and also turned off **fast start-up**

What to do in this situation? Please help me out. I want to merge all other windows partitions back to **C** drive and make it as a single partition again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have too many recovery partitions! But it might be the way your system was set up by your OEM, so who knows. You should not delete and merge recovery partitions into your C: partition unless you're sure you don'tneed them. From your screenshot, partitions 15.83 GB, 7.45 GB and 191.48 GB were probably created by Ubuntu and are safe to delete/merge.

To check which partitions were created by Ubuntu, I would use the Ubuntu USB to boot into the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option and use GParted (the file system on those partitions would probably be ext2 etc. or linuxswap, which I'm guessing is not detected by Disk Management in Windows).

You can then delete the partitions you want and merge the unallocated space into the existing NTFS (C:) partition, but it's probably safer to do that through Windows rather than GParted. I found [this article](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/merge-partitions-freeware.html) that has details on how to do that.

Again, you should probably stay away from the recovery partitions unless you know what you're doing. The same goes for the EFI partition, which is probably used by Windows and would make it unbootable if deleted.

As always, if you're editing partitions with valuable data, you should **make backups first**.

Comment: Thanks @Ratler. Yes those partitions 15.83 GB, 7.45 GB and 191.48 GB are for ubuntu which I created during install.

Comment: Have you managed to merge them back into your C: partition?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an efi partition during install? I guess that's the problem.
I hope you know a proper procedure on how to install any Linux OS.
I'll still mention, check what you missed out.

1. A partition to install system files. (Ext4 and mount point "/")
2. A partition for the home directory.(Not necessary but i recommend; Ext 4; mp "/home")
3. An efi partition to install a bootloader. (flagged as esp or something similar; no mount point; keep it 2 GB or 1GB at least; must be on the same disk as the one you chose to install bootloader). Many people including me fail at this part.

I hope this fixes the problem. Comment if you face any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I remember that I haven't created EFI partition during install. I only created three partitions as per the [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/) root, home and swap.

Comment: I hope it helped